# Obtener un valor numérico en Discord bot Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Mi problema es que intento hacer un bot que sea capaz de llevar un recuento monetario de los usuarios, pero cuando utilizo la función de sumar, en el segundo `split` del contenido del mensaje no sé que poner exactamente para que lo interprete como un número

```javascript
if(command == "sumar"){
  var parts = message.content.split(' ');
  (parts[0] = message.mentions.members.first());
  (parts[1] = Number);
  console.log(parts[1]);
        
  if(!parts[0]) return message.reply('Necesitas mencionar a un usuario para poder sumar');
  if(!parts[1]) return message.reply('Necesitas poner un número');

  dinero_db.sumar(`${message.guild.id}.${message.author.id}.dinero`, parts[1])
  console.log(`${message.mentions.id}, ganaste: ${parts[1]}`)
  return;
}
```

Cuando se deja el mensaje (el prefijo, la mención del usuario a sumar y el número, detecta la mención pero no el número después como cantidad)

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Te sugiero también que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Por favor agrega un ejemplo de un mensaje y la salida o el resultado esperado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el metodo `parseInt()` para ello:

```js
dinero_db.sumar(`${message.guild.id}.${message.author.id}.dinero`, parseInt(parts[1]));
```

con este metodo, `parts[1]` se agregará como un número en la db.

Espero haberte ayudado.